# htaccess rule to rewrite url wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I am running multisite in localhost for now. the urls are as follow. 
- localhost/area-guides
- localhost/area-guides/school-guides

Its a sub-directory installation. What I want to achieve is have multisite url at same level. 
changing `localhost/area-guides/school-guides` to `localhost/school-guides`.

Tried out few different things but no luck at all.

Comment: Of course you could put what you've already tried here.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to edit the following files..

1. Edit `localhost/.htaccess` :

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
   RewriteRule ^(/school-guides)?$ area-guides/school-guides [L]
   ```

And add another subdirectory just like the `school-guides` rules above.

Comment: but there doesn't exist any directory area-guides/school-guides/.

Comment: You want to redirect `localhost/area-guides/school-guides` to `localhost/school-guides` right? So if the `area-guides/school-guides/` doesn't exist, then what's the parent & sub directory name?

Comment: I dont want to redirect to school-guides. home directory from where the site is loaded is named as area-guides. 
I am running multisite feature of wordpress. And by default the multisite url starts from area-guides/newURL, area-guides/newURL2. 
at area-guides another site is running.
Hope this clears my initial problem.